# Additional file entity fields in widget_form

Tags: forms, files

I've added additional fields to my file entity types and would like to have them in upload widget, just like file description.

How can I add my custom fields element using field_widget_form_alter? (if that's the way to go)

Comment: You should give the Media module (in Core) a try. It provides a Media File Entity Type which can easily be extended with more fields.

Comment: I am using file_entity and added fields to my file types, problem is I want them to show in upload widget.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the field type, not entity type.  Extend `FileItem` and override propertyDefinitions() to add it to the field properties. Like the description you've mentioned was added by `FileItem` extending `EntityReferenceItem`:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);

    $properties['display'] = DataDefinition::create('boolean')
      ->setLabel(t('Display'))
      ->setDescription(t('Flag to control whether this file should be displayed when viewing content'));

    $properties['description'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Description'));

    return $properties;
  }
```

Comment: forgot to say I am on D7.

Comment: Should be the same concept in D7, field properties and entity fields are different.

Comment: Found this module installed: [File entity inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_inline) it works pretty well, I am now digging into the code trying to understand it better. Thank you

Comment: too hurry... form field are showed but not saved.